# Loop through two different lists — jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, slideshow

I've made a very simple slideshow. Clicking on the arrow will fade the `$(this)` out, and the next slide will `fadeIn()` using the `next()` function. The reverse in reverse.

However, this does **not** seem to work when there are multiple slideshows on the same page.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/zYnYM/11/)

jQuery:

```
    $('li').first().siblings().hide();

        $('.next').click(function () {
            $(this)
                .parent('.container')
                .find('li:first-child')
                .fadeOut(function

 () {
            $(this)
                .next()
                .fadeIn()
            $(this)
                .appendTo('ul')
        });

    });

    $('.back').click(function () {
        $(this)
            .parent('.container')
            .find('li:first-child')
            .fadeOut(function () {
            $(this)
                .parent('.container')
                .find('li:last-child')
                .fadeIn()
                .prependTo('ul')
        });

    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="inner_box">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="back">back</div>
    <div class="next">next</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <ul class="inner_box">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="back">back</div>
    <div class="next">next</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you think this line does: `$('li').first().siblings().hide();`? Specifically the `.first()`

Comment: Hide all siblings of the first `li` ?

Comment: yes, the first of the page, not the first of every `ul` set

Comment: Exactly the _first `li` on the page_.

Comment: btw, `appendTo('ul')` will also append to both the `ul`s on the page

Comment: alternate version http://jsfiddle.net/zYnYM/22/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('.container').find('li:first-child').siblings().hide();

$('.next').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this), $ul = $(this).siblings('ul');

    $ul.find('li:first-child').fadeOut(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.next().fadeIn();
        $this.appendTo($ul)
    });

});

$('.back').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this), $ul = $(this).siblings('ul');

    $ul.find('li:first-child').fadeOut(function () {
        $ul.find('li:last-child').prependTo($ul).fadeIn()
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tTB3r/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hiding the first li on the page, loop through each .inner_box element and hide the all but the first li elements.

```
$('ul.inner_box').each(function() {
  $(this).find('li').first().siblings().hide();  
});
```

Comment: or just do `$('li').not(':first-child').hide()`?

Comment: This helps, but then the `.back` button breaks it. http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/zYnYM/16/

Answer (score 0):

New JS (tested, [working in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zYnYM/20/))

```
$('.container').each(function() {

    $(this).find('li').first().siblings().hide();

    $(this).find('.next').click(function () {
        $(this)
            .parent('.container')
            .find('li:first-child')
            .fadeOut(function () {
            $(this)
                .next()
                .fadeIn()
            $(this)
                .appendTo('ul')
        });

    });

    $(this).find('.back').click(function () {
        $(this)
            .parent('.container')
            .find('li:first-child')
            .fadeOut(function () {
            $(this)
                .parent('.container')
                .find('li:last-child')
                .fadeIn()
                .prependTo('ul')
        });

    });

});
```

So basically you wrap the whole thing in `$('.container').each` and tweak the selectors inside so it does the whole thing once for each instance of `.container` and they don't interfere with one another.